# how to call the value of selected option in controller?

Tags: angularjs

```
 <div class="field-wrap">
    <select name=courses class="input-field1"  name="state" title="state" ng-model="signup.state" >
                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                    <option value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
                    <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                    <option value="Arunachal Pradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
                    <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
                    <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
                    <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                    <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
                    <option value="Dadra and Nagar Haveli">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
                    <option value="Daman and Diu">Daman and Diu</option>
                    <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                    <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
                    <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
                    <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
                    <option value="Himachal Pradesh">Himachal Pradesh</option>
                    <option value="Jammu and Kashmir">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                    <option value="Jharkhand">Jharkhand</option>
                    <option value="Karnataka">Karnataka</option>
                    <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
                    <option value="Lakshadweep">Lakshadweep</option>
                    <option value="Madhya Pradesh">Madhya Pradesh</option>
                    <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
                    <option value="Manipur">Manipur</option>
                    <option value="Meghalaya">Meghalaya</option>
                    <option value="Mizoram">Mizoram</option>
                    <option value="Nagaland">Nagaland</option>
                    <option value="Orissa">Orissa</option>
                    <option value="Pondicherry">Pondicherry</option>
                    <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
                    <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
                    <option value="Sikkim">Sikkim</option>
                    <option value="Tamil Nadu">Tamil Nadu</option>
                    <option value="Tripura">Tripura</option>
                    <option value="Uttaranchal">Uttaranchal</option>
                    <option value="Uttar Pradesh">Uttar Pradesh</option>
                    <option value="West Bengal">West Bengal</option>
                    </select>
        </div>
```

this is the select menu i am using i want to fetch the selected value in my controller but don't know how to do that, I already fetched the value for textbox but have no idea about the select box.

```
$scope.signupForm = function() {
                        if ($scope.signup_form.$valid) {
                            var data = {
                                firstname : $scope.signup_form.firstname.$modelValue,
                                lastname : $scope.signup_form.lastname.$modelValue,
                                email : $scope.signup_form.email.$modelValue,
                                mobileNumber : $scope.signup_form.mobileNumber.$modelValue,
                                district : $scope.signup_form.district.$modelValue,
                                state : $scope.signup_form.state.$modelValue,
                                course : $scope.signup_form.course.$modelValue,
                                collegeName : $scope.signup_form.collegeName.$modelValue,

                            };
```

This is my controller, I think I have to use ng-option but not sure.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case $scope.signup.state will have value of selected state. 
The value of selected option is saved into model assigned to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding an array of options in your Controller instead of hardcoding it in the HTML and then use the ng-options directive to display the options from that array, you'd end up with something like:

```
<select name=courses class="input-field1"  name="state" title="state" ng-model="signup.state" ng-options="option in options">
```

(where options is an array of options declared inside your controller

```
$scope.options = ['option1', 'option2'];
```

Then you can simply bind that input to an ng-model and use it regularly from the controller

```
$scope.signup.state
```

will give you access to whatever option is selected

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` here. When ever an option is selected from the drop down then this method will be fired and we can persist the selected option data.

**html**

```
<div>
    <select  ng-model="selState" ng-change="selectedState(selState)" 
     data-ng-options="state as state.name for state in states">
        <option value="">Select Account</option>
    </select> 
   {{selectedState}}     
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.states=[
                        {name:"AP"},
                        {name:"Karnataka"},
                        {name:"Tamilnadu"}
                      ];

        $scope.selectedState = function(item) {
          alert(item.name);
        };
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gOw0vh6SyNv5SkBeUFZI?p=preview)